# Python3 pip3 can't install requests

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip, python-requests

On my Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop I have python2.7.12 and python3.6.1 installed.

```
seept@seept:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
seept@seept:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.1
```

And I also installed pip and pip3. Is it true that pip is for python2 and pip3 is for python3?

So why the hell both versions of pip shows me this:

```
seept@seept:~$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/seept/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
seept@seept:~$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/seept/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

Why Python 3.5?

```
seept@seept:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python

seept@seept:~$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

seept@seept:~$ which pip
/home/seept/.local/bin/pip

seept@seept:~$ which pip3
/home/seept/.local/bin/pip3
```

So my real problem is that I need the module 'requests' for a python3 project.

When I run:

```
seept@seept:~$ sudo pip3 install requests
```

This is the output:

```
The directory '/home/seept/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/seept/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
**Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages**
```

By the way I always get this message:

```
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So this output says I am using pip verison 8.1.1 but when I run `pip --version` it says me I am running version 9.0.1.

For me it looks like I already messed it up and should reinstall all?

Comment: Your `pip` lives in `/home/seept/.local/bin/pip`, so presumably you have a Python 3.5 install or virtualenv there too. Use `python3 -m pip` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run your project with virtualenv. It keeps safe your project directory and avoids conflict with other versions well.

Go to your project directory and just install first virtualenv using:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Before installing your packages run this to activate virtualenv:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Now your directory is safe and you can install your package here to remain safe and unique from another directory.

Hope you understand my concept.

Thanks.